# How to write opencv cv::Mat image directly in boost shared memory

Tags: c++, opencv, boost

I have two processes who want to share cv::Mat image information, and I want to use the boost managed_shared_memory to realize it. Since copying an image is really time consuming, so I am trying to find a way to write the image directly to the shared memory when it first appears.

However, since cv::Mat is only a header who has the a pointer to the image data, and the data locates somewhere else, I couldn't realize my idea. I have some test code but they are very chaos and can not work, so I think I am in the totally wrong direction. Anyone has experience about this? thank you!

Comment: did you profile the application to check if the copying is really an issue in your case? `cv::Mat` has a constructor accepting preallocated data pointer, maybe you could use that somehow?

Comment: Thanks @slawekwin! I think it's a great issue in my case since my images are all 3 Megapixel large and I must ensure the speed of the image updating as well. I tried already with memcpy(), the only problem is the speed.

Comment: IMHO I wouldn't share the `cv::Mat` object itself, as correct reference counting may get a bit tricky. Instead I'd consider sharing the byte array (or some class encapsulating that?) that provides the memory storage for the `cv::Mat` object.

Answer (score 2):

The cv::Mat.ptr() function gives you the first pointer of an OpenCV image.

The size of the data buffer is equal to Channels * Height * Width * elmsize, so you can just use 
`memcpy(dest, image.ptr(), Channels * Height * Width)` if the elements are 1 byte each (based on CvType).

Caveats:
    - The image must be continuous. Use isContinuous() to check. If it fails, clone() the image to get a continuous copy.
    - To retrieve the image from Shared memory, you will have to construct a new cv:Mat with the same height, width, channels, CvType and step. Then use memcpy.

See [Shared Memory Example](https://github.com/iamsurya/minimal-working-examples/tree/master/OpenCV-SharedMemory) for a minimal working example.